# Create iCloud Mail account without an Apple device

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I have already an Apple ID through iTunes. I am a Windows user and have no Apple devices, but would like to have an iCloud.com email address.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't think so, as that only addresses it if you have an Apple device. To my knowledge, however, you can't do it anyways if you don't have an Apple device, so there's that.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? It seems to be impossible without an actual device.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to iOS devices and Macs, Apple IDs can be created on other platforms via Apple's native apps such as iTunes, Apple Music, and Apple TV+.

> ### Create an Apple ID on your Windows PC
>
> 1. Open iTunes for Windows. Make sure that you have the latest version.
> 2. From the menu bar at the top of your computer screen or at the top of the iTunes window, choose Account > Sign In. Then click Create New Apple ID.
>
> ### Create an Apple ID on another device
>
> To create an Apple ID on an Apple TV, **Android device, smart TV, or streaming device**, you can usually follow the steps provided onscreen and enter your full name, date of birth, an email address or phone number, and a payment method. You need to create an Apple ID when you subscribe to services like Apple Music and Apple TV+, or when you download the Apple TV app.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204316

Comment: An ID isn't sufficient to create an email address.

Answer (score 0):

I googled around and no answer about this problem, the condition you can create iCloud email address is you own an Apple device.
On an iOS device, go to Settings > iCloud, turn on Mail, then follow the onscreen instructions. On a Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click iCloud, select Mail, then follow the onscreen instructions.